# Displaying HTML entity &Gt; in title

Tags: php, xhtml

I'm trying to display a ≫ HTML entity in a page title, but they do not show up in some browser title bars.

Firefox 4 displays the proper ≫ symbol in its title bar, but IE and Firefox 3 shows the symbols as &Gt;

So titles in Firefox will be :

Fruit ≫ Bananas ≫ Peeled

but some display:

Fruit &Gt; Bananas &Gt; Peeled

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `»`?

```
&#187;  &raquo;     angle quotation mark (right)
```

Comment: Fantastic, this fixed my problem, tested in IE8 so far and it's working. No more literals in the title bar.

Answer (score 3):

Just a thought, your title included a capital G in the `&Gt;` have you tried all lowercase `&gt;`

Comment: No &Gt; and &gt; are not the same entity. I want $Gt;, with capital G. ;)